# A conic inside a hexagon

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, conic-sections, projective-geometry, polygons

Can you prove or disprove the following claim:

> Construct a hexagon circumscribed around a conic section. Intersection points of its non-principal diagonals lie on a new conic section.

[image]

GeoGebra applet that demonstrates this claim can be found [here](https://www.geogebra.org/m/bwyntepx).

Comment: And the conic section may not necessarily be an ellipse.

Comment: It is sufficient to prove this when the hexagon is circumscribed about a *circle*. (This will not necessarily make the derived conic a circle.) The fact that all (non-degenerate) conics are "projectively equivalent" to a circle helps with understanding many such results (for instance, [Pascal's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_theorem)), and exploiting that fact often streamlines proofs.

Comment: You might consider reposting the heptagon version that you deleted a few months ago.

Comment: @brainjam https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4069038/15660

Comment: @PeđaTerzić I remember you posted a similar problem about 3 principal diagonals meeting a point and 6 circumcenters lying a conic. Where is the post now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a consequence of Pascal and Brianchon's Theorems.

The intersections of the non-principal diagonals can also be seen as the intersections of the triangles $\triangle{DBF}$ and $\triangle{CAE}$.  By Brianchon's theorem, the principal diagonals $EB,FC,AD$ are concurrent at a point $X$.  Thus the two triangles are perspective.  A converse of Pascal's theorem says that the points of intersection of two perspective triangles lie on a common conic.

Details and more precise statements can be found in Hatton's [*Projective Geometry, pg 189*](https://archive.org/details/cu31924060184045/page/n203/mode/2up).  There you can find Pascal's theorem, its converse, Brianchon's theorem and proofs.