# Generalizations to Brianchon's theorem?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, projective-geometry

I'm wondering if people know of a generalization of Brianchon's theorem. Is there a studied criterion to have a conic (or ellipse) inscribed in a polygon with more than six sides?

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is limited, but you can look at [The Heptagon Theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4072748/1257).  The question for that link shows that diagonals of a heptagon with an inscribed conic meet at seven co-conical points.  And because the theorem is self dual, I believe this works in reverse.

The theorem comes from Evelyn et al, *The Seven Circles Theorem and Other New Theorems*.  That book also talks about the case of $2n$-sided polygons with inscribed conics, and how the diagonals meet on curves of order $n-2$.

So there are generalizations of Brianchon's theorem to polygons with more than six sides, but involve higher order curves rather than single points.

For another take on this see [Katz, *Curves In Cages: An Algebro-geometric Zoo*](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0508076.pdf), especially Theorem 3.3 (The Mystic 2d-gram). The latter is expressed as a generalization of Pascal's Theorem, but it should dualize to a generalization of Brianchon's Theorem.